Gcloud app deploy golang error with private repo imports on Windows
So I have a Google App Engine Golang application I need to update. My code is located in a private repo, https://github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate . My app.yaml and so on are in https://github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/tree/main/app, but my source code also imports from other folders in TestGoPrivate like https://github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/Work.
When I run gcloud app deploy app.yaml cron.yaml --no-promote --project testgoprivate -v testgoprivate-2024-10-09 I get errors like:
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 292cbe9e-04dc-470b-b054-6e625fc33e01 status: FAILURE
go: downloading go1.22.8 (linux/amd64)
go: github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/app imports
        github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/Work: github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/Work@v1.0.0: replacement directory ./github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/Work does not exist
go: github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/app imports
        google.golang.org/appengine/v2: github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/Work@v1.0.0 (replaced by ./github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/Work): reading github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/Work/go.mod: open /layers/google.go.appengine-gomod/srv/github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/Work/go.mod: no such file or directory
Full build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=asia-southeast1/292cbe9e-04dc-470b-b054-6e625fc33e01?project=441925606269

Earlier I was getting some GitHub errors, so I went to https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https , created a GitHub Personal Access Token that is a Fine-grained token with only Read access to code and metadata.
Then I created a file _netrc (read somewhere .netrc under Windows should be _netrc) under %HOME% and filled it with one line:
machine github.com login ThePiachu password github_pat_<PASSWORD>
But then I try doing gcloud app deploy and I keep getting the same errors.
I tried looking for some way to enable terminal prompts, or set that username / password, or do anything else but to no avail. I haven't had this issue a year back, last time I tried updating the app, but something changed since and I can't figure out how to solve this issue...
EDIT:
My Go version is 1.22.8, my go.mod is under ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/app. The package under /app is main and under /Work the package is Work.
EDIT2:
Here is a simplified repo copy that gets the same error - https://github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate . I updated the go.mod to use the local code with replace github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/Work => ./github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/Work but that didn't solve the issue just changed it...

Go shouldn't need a (GitHub) access token to access other packages in the same (and locally cloned) module. What version of Go? Where is go.mod? It's curious that app.yaml is is the repo's /app folder (rather than the root folder). It works but it's not good practice to use capitalized package names. I suspect that your app is misconfigured such that app and Work are both modules (they probably shouldn't be). Please update the question with more details. A minimal repro is expected not just a statement of an error.

@DazWilkin My Go version is 1.23.2, my go.mod is under ThePiachu/GoPrivate/app. The package under /app is main and under /Work the package is Work. The location of app.yaml and such might be legacy since I've used this repo for like a decade and it seems GAE changes how everything is done every year so probably at some point in the past things needed to be under /app. And again, this code used to work just fine a year ago, now I'm trying to update it since I need v2 code for logging to work...
I'll work on putting together some sample repo when I have some time...

Thanks for the clarification. So, you have 2 modules within the repo. Presumably (!?) in the go.mod under app, you have a github.com/ThePiachu/GoPrivate/Work entry that has been cached locally (and thus works) but isn't cached when App Engine deploys,  it attempts the go get but balks at the repo being private. See use private dependencies

@DazWilkin - okay, here is the simplified repo - https://github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/tree/main . Updated the issue body to reflect the exact printouts I'm getting and so on.

Started narrowing the problems down. First issue was go.mod and go.sum missing, then it was a problem of the example of private import I was using being deceptive, and now I'm stuck figuring out how app.yaml wants me to specify which html files to upload, fun!

Okay, so the big issue was the correct placement of files.
It used to be that /app folder was the root of the Google App Engine Go project - that's where the app.yaml used to go and so on. But now it seems GAE wants to treat the top level of the repo as the main folder.
So my first problem was trying to put go.mod and go.sum into app. No, it went to the root folder above app. That will probably be enough to solve importing issues within the repo (so /app/main.go importing from /Work) since you are still within the same project. gcloud app deploy shouldn't be complaining about it.
But if you are importing from a different private repo, I think that's where I stumbled upon my other error. I saw some blog post somewhere giving an example that basically looked like: replace github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/Work => ./github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/Work and I thought to myself "ah, so the dot stands in for GOPATH, and I just specify the full import path from there!". As it turns out no, the dot specifies the folder where go.mod is and things relative from it. So in this example I would go replace github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/Work => ./Work. The blog itself imported the private repo directly into the other repo and thus the confusion.
I think there might also be something about specifying GOPRIVATE inside of go envlikeset GOPRIVATE=github.com/ThePiachu/TestGoPrivate/*`, but I'm not sure if that contributed to anything or not since I set it so early in the process.
So yeah, the main issue was correctly placing the files and going from there. Didn't help that I had a lot of other issues that also coincided with it so figuring it out took a while...
